# Does "Isaac Asimov's Robots in Time" series violate the grandfather paradox?

Tags: time-travel, robots, isaac-asimov, paradox, william-f-wu

As anyone who is familiar with the [*Isaac Asimov's Robots in Time* series by William F. Wu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov%27s_Robots_in_Time) is already aware, the Mojave Center Governor does not realize that sending his component parts backwards through time results in nuclear explosions and thus erasing them from history. Once the human/robot team is created to travel back in time to to retrieve the components, how does this not introduce a grandfather paradox such that the components would never have existed in that time period once they are collected?

Comment: How would that cause them never to have existed? They retrieve the components after they arrive. The personal timeline of the components and the team is still linear; it never crosses over itself, as far as I can remember.

Comment: I don't understand how that would violate the grandfather paradox based on how you described it, to me it seems that they sent a part to the past, realized sending it back in time was a mistake, and send in a team to retrieve the parts in the past, at no time did they do anything that would have made them not send the parts to the past

Answer (score 1):

I think SaintWacko has the answer, but this question has gone unanswered for 10 years.

The grandfather paradox is two pristine cases of event A and event not-A, where event not-A + time-travel generates event A, and event A + time-travel generates event not-A.

It is a loop:
[image: "state A" leads to "state not A" leading back to "state A" again]

They inserted a second transformation into sequence such loop that did not generate state not-A, aka they removed the nuclear explosion.  That stops it from being that type of loop.

[image: "state A" leads to "state not A" but does not back to "state A" anymore, instead flowing to "state B"]